# Is it possible to convert 'dynamic' excel formulas to python code?

Tags: python, excel, formula, pycel

Is it possible to convert excel formulas to python code? For example:

```
     "=TEXT(SORT(PROPER(UNIQUE(FILTER("
            "ws_1!A:A,ws_2!B:B=ws_3!C3"
            ')))), "")'
```

Or it is not possible. I was looking into Pycel, xlcalculator, formulas module. But unfortunately i cannot find more complicated example than sum(A,B).

Probably i could do it with pandas, but it won't work constantly in spreadsheet. Or can i save some python script instead formula to cell?

if you have any idea how to translate easier formulas eg. or any library that can do it, I would be grateful for the tips :

```
'=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,ws!A2:B3,2,0), "Invalid")'
```

My motivation is to avoid a long excel formula in python code. And make it testable

Comment: Highly doubt this is possible. What exactly is your end goal? Why are you working with formulas to begin with? If you use `win32com`, you can use Excel's calculation engine to calculate the formula for you, but that still begs the question, why you're using formulas in the first place.

Comment: @BigBen I am using formulas to deal with data between spreadsheet. And i created interactive excel app with python, but i cant get rid off ugly and unreadable excel. Plus ideally i want to write some tests to excel formula

Comment: I think you'll have to use `win32com` then.